# Setting up Windows 2008 R2 Std as Internet Gateway

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to set up my Windows 2008 server as an internet gateway. Is the only option Microsoft ISA Server or Microsoft Forefront Threat Management Gateway? Any open source software or built in configs to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Just learnt that older versions of ISA Server e.g. 2006 do not work with Windows 2008 R2. So the only option is Microsoft Forefront TMG. Instead of using Forefront TMG, I added `Routing and Remote Access` in my server's roles and configured it for VPN access and NAT. That did the trick perfectly for both my remote VPN clients as well as local network users.